# Parsing BLS JSON with R

Tags: json, r, parsing

I would like to run some canned reports with Knitr in R relying on a number of third party resources, some offered as text files, and some offered through public APIs.

I am not particulary well versed parsing JSON files, however, and quickly lose my bearings when they get mildly complicated (which I don't particularly think my example is, anyway, but still.)

Here's the call:

```
library(rjson)
addr = 'http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/ENU0607510010'
json_data <- fromJSON(file=addr, method='C')
```

Here's what it looks like--any way to stuff that into a dataframe for further (automatic) melting and plotting?

```
> str(json_data)[1:100]
List of 4
 $ status      : chr "REQUEST_SUCCEEDED"
 $ responseTime: num 14
 $ message     : list()
 $ Results     :List of 1
  ..$ series:List of 1
  .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ seriesID: chr "ENU0607510010"
  .. .. ..$ data    :List of 35
  .. .. .. ..$ :List of 5
  .. .. .. .. ..$ year      : chr "2013"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ period    : chr "M09"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ periodName: chr "September"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ value     : chr "615958"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ footnotes :List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ code: chr "P"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ text: chr "   Preliminary."
  .. .. .. ..$ :List of 5
  .. .. .. .. ..$ year      : chr "2013"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ period    : chr "M08"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ periodName: chr "August"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ value     : chr "615326"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ footnotes :List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ code: chr "P"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ text: chr "   Preliminary."
  .. .. .. ..$ :List of 5
  .. .. .. .. ..$ year      : chr "2013"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ period    : chr "M07"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ periodName: chr "July"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ value     : chr "611071"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ footnotes :List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ code: chr "P"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ text: chr "   Preliminary."
  .. .. .. ..$ :List of 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go. I need to move from `RJSONIO` to `jsonlite` at some point, but this will get you your data. It's all a matter of figuring out the structure so you can do the `sapply`'s. I added the bar chart because I had it in a gist example for BLS data already.

```
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
library(ggplot2)

bls.content <- getURLContent("http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/ENU0607510010")
bls.json <- fromJSON(bls.content, simplify=TRUE)
tmp <-bls.json$Results[[1]][[1]]
bls.df <- data.frame(year=sapply(tmp$data,"[[","year"),
                     period=sapply(tmp$data,"[[","period"),
                     periodName=sapply(tmp$data,"[[","periodName"),
                     value=as.numeric(sapply(tmp$data,"[[","value")), 
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

head(bls.df, n=10)
##    year period periodName  value
## 1  2013    M09  September 615958
## 2  2013    M08     August 615326
## 3  2013    M07       July 611071
## 4  2013    M06       June 610893
## 5  2013    M05        May 610750
## 6  2013    M04      April 607797
## 7  2013    M03      March 603286
## 8  2013    M02   February 600868
## 9  2013    M01    January 593770
## 10 2012    M13     Annual 586538

gg <- ggplot(data=bls.df, aes(x=year, y=value, group=period)) 
gg <- gg + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", aes(fill=period))
gg
```

[image]

Comment: it was a `sapply` question, then! Elegant. Why the shift from `RJSONIO` to `jsonlite` ?

Comment: `jsonlite` is a fork of `RJSONIO` and I think the mapping from JSON to R objects make alot more sense. http://www.r-bloggers.com/new-package-jsonlite-a-smarter-json-encoderdecoder/ has a fairly decent explanation. Glad the BLS code makes sense :-)